# Setting up a Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, editor, content-type, custom-post-type, backend

I'm busy with a Custom Post Type and I've got a question.

Would it be possible to put this in a CPT ->

**image** (atm i'm using thumbnail)

**3 content tabs** (got 3 links on the page, each link has to represent his content, content+title)

**A timeline system** (atm not really sure how i gonna make the timeline)

I want this to fit in a single Custom Post Type, If i can get like 3 editors it would be great and then transform *"the_content();"*  into the_content1,2,3.

This is the layout -> [image: http://i.imgur.com/KL9mpuI.png]

And here is the website so you can see what I already got http://erwin.my89.nl/stage/sieh/#

Current CPT ->
[image: http://i.imgur.com/nGyQuiV.png]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this might be related -> http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/138064/adding-multiple-wysiwyg-editors-to-custom-post-type

Comment: Oh well. I used this one http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/14/advanced-layout-templates-in-wordpress-content-editor/ , Now i only need to attach them to the nav links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it trough this link:  http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/14/advanced-layout-templates-in-wordpress-content-editor/ :)